# Editorconfig rule or bash to indent whitespace lines to previous/cloned indent level

Tags: bash, whitespace, indentation, editorconfig

I would like to make an editorconfig rule or bash script which, for each line that is only whitespace, indent it to the same indent level as the previous line but only if the current line contains nothing but whitespace or newline.

Here's an example of a desired before and after (Rainbow colors == whitespace):

[image: clone indent depth]

and here's an example of replacing newline with cloned indent:

[image: newline to cloned indent]

I could do it in Python or Nim but it's really a job for editorconfig or bash script. I figure some sed or awk wizard can make quick work of it.

**Note:** My whitespace is set to 4 spaces.

Comment: A language-aware formatting tool would be better suited.

Comment: @Shawn Not in this case since having an empty line doesn't violate PEP8